# Advice on troubleshooting Wagtail/SQL Azure compatibility required

Tags: python, sql-server, django, azure-sql-database, wagtail

My organisation is developing a new publishing platform based on Wagtail as a CMS backend. We have extensive in-house expertise in MS SQL databases, but next to none with Postgres or MySQL so would prefer to utilise MS SQL (specifically SQL Azure) - which Wagtail's docs seem to suggest is possible.

I have an instance of Wagtail running and have installed a Django backend (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-pyodbc-azure) that claims to support SQL Azure. I have configured my database connection settings in settings.py.

I can successfully run migrations and create a superuser, so I am reasonably confident that the database connectivity is good.

I can then browse to the Wagtail login page at http://localhost:8000/admin but immediately upon logging in with the credentials provided to the createsuperuser script, I get the following error:

> ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL
>   Server]Incorrect syntax near 'LIMIT'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

It would seem that Wagtail itself is using this LIMIT keyword which is unsupported in MS SQL - what's my best approach for troubleshooting and attempting to resolve this behaviour? Or am I on a hiding to nothing?

**offending SQL :**

```
SELECT wp.* FROM wagtailcore_pagerevision wp
JOIN ( SELECT max(created_at) AS max_created_at,
page_id FROM wagtailcore_pagerevision WHERE user_id = %s 
GROUP BY page_id ORDER BY max_created_at DESC LIMIT %s ) AS max_rev ON max_rev.max_created_at = wp.created_at ORDER BY wp.created_at DESC
```

Comment: The offending bit of SQL appears to be: `            SELECT wp.* FROM
                wagtailcore_pagerevision wp JOIN (
                    SELECT max(created_at) AS max_created_at, page_id FROM
                        wagtailcore_pagerevision WHERE user_id = %s GROUP BY page_id ORDER BY max_created_at DESC LIMIT %s
                ) AS max_rev ON max_rev.max_created_at = wp.created_at ORDER BY wp.created_at DESC` from wagtail/wagtailadmin/views/home.py

Comment: SQLServer doesn't have `LIMIT` keyword.use `TOP` instead

Comment: Note that Wagtail doesn't officially support SQL Server at present. In the past users have successfully got Wagtail working with SQL Server, and contributed patches to provide MS SQL compatibility, but there's currently no ongoing QA testing to ensure that it remains compatible. Unfortunately it looks like this query slipped in during Wagtail 1.7 and has gone unreported up to now.

Comment: I haven't tested since 1.7, sorry! I've made a note to take a look at the migration and include a SQL Server friendly version.

Comment: I've got a patch for this started. It isn't pretty, but it'll work until Django 1.11 is required by Wagtail and we can do sub-selects in the ORM!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the responses, all.

We managed to get things working in the end by hacking the awkward bit of SQL and discovered that it was the only thing causing any issues (so that's good news!)

I also upgraded to 1.9 without seeing any other problems, so it looks positive.

Our modification is

```
        last_edits = PageRevision.objects.raw(
        """
        SELECT wp.* FROM
            wagtailcore_pagerevision wp JOIN (
                SELECT TOP 5 max(created_at) AS max_created_at, page_id FROM
                    wagtailcore_pagerevision WHERE user_id = %s GROUP BY page_id ORDER BY max_created_at DESC
            ) AS max_rev ON max_rev.max_created_at = wp.created_at ORDER BY wp.created_at DESC
         """, [self.request.user.pk])
```

We'll likely be progressing this further, and considering Tom D's suggested approach of simply wrapping this in an if...else block to allow for different db connections.

Answer (score 1):

For the most part, Wagtail uses Django's ORM, which supports MS SQL. There are some cases where we drop into 'raw' SQL, typically for performance reasons. In this case, the raw SQL isn't compatible with MS SQL, as you point out. There are two approaches you could take to resolve this:

1. Refactor the code to use the Django ORM (checking any performance implications)
2. Provide a special case for MS SQL, e.g.

https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/da067679cdd7999c256c8916f78c82f7641d51cd/wagtail/wagtailcore/models.py#L602